# How to get bullet points when parsing text with Jsoup?

Tags: android, kotlin, jsoup

I am using Jsoup to get the text from an html doc and display it in my android app.

The text cotains a list (<ul><li>).

If I do it like this I get only the text:

```
val doc = Jsoup.parse(someHtml)
        return doc.text()
```

I tried using wholeText:

```
val doc = Jsoup.parse(removeImages)
        return doc.wholeText()
```

In this way it keeps some formatting, but still it ignores the bullet points. Is there any way to get the bullet points in the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bullets are rendered by the browser, so they are not a part of the text.
You'll have to add it by yourself, like in this example:

```
String html = "<html>" +
            "<head>" +
            "<title>List</title>" +
            "</head>" +
            "<body>" +
             "<ul>" +
              "<li>Item 1</li>" +
              "<li>Item 2</li>" +
              "<li>Item 3</li>" +
            "</ul> " +
            "</body>" +
            "</html>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element list = doc.select("ul").first();
Elements item = list.children();
for (Element e : item) {
    System.out.println("\u2022" + e.text());
}
```

The output is:

•Item 1
•Item 2
•Item 3
You can replace the bullet with any other character that you like, by replacing the `\u2022` code with any other valid code/character.